# Unable to run any MongoDB command on Heroku

Tags: mongodb, heroku

I am making a Restful API Golang With MongoDB. I have this error message from MongoDB & heroku

"not authorized on databaseName to execute command".

This is working locally but not on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I specified the wrong database name in my code. You have to use the database name that heroku is giving you.

For example in golang

Before

```
db := mgo.Dial(mongodAddress).session.DB("myDatabasename")
```

After

```
db := mgo.Dial(mongodAddress).session.DB("heroku_7s46ta3a")
```

heroku_7s46ta3a is here a example name of the database name provided by heroku.